# include_once: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Cakephp 2.4.5

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to Cakephp, I am trying to install it. I extract everything and create the needed files/folders, now there is the following error:

```
Warning (2): include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelBuddy\app\Config\database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [CORE\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 67]

Warning (2): include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelBuddy\app\Config\database.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelBuddy\lib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') [CORE\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 67]
```

The file `database.php` does not exists. Do I have to create it?

Here is the code of `ConnectionManager` where the problem is:

```
protected static function _init() {
    include_once APP . 'Config' . DS . 'database.php';
    if (class_exists('DATABASE_CONFIG')) {
        self::$config = new DATABASE_CONFIG();
    }
    self::$_init = true;
}
```

Comment: The warning message clearly tells you that the file is not exist,you should have to create it and write the DB connections there

Comment: please see what `APP . 'Config' . DS . 'database.php'` is. Maybe the `APP` constant has not been properly defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create inside: `app/Config` a file called `database.php`

now you need to configure your database connection like:

```
    <?php

    class DATABASE_CONFIG {

        public $default = array (
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'yourusermysql',
            'password' => 'passwordmysql',
            'database' => 'nameofdatabase',
            'prefix' => ''
        );

        public $test = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            'database' => 'test_database_name',
            'prefix' => '',
            //'encoding' => 'utf8',
        );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the given error you should do

```
if (class_exists('DATABASE_CONFIG', FALSE)) {
    self::$config = new DATABASE_CONFIG();
}
```

i was struggling with same problem, but if the class didn't exist it should perform the remaining operation, and not giving me a fatal error.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure the database.php file is committed in your git repo. Checkout the .gitignore file.